# outouchend not removing hover when modal window opens

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a button with hover that changes opacity. It is social button that shares info to facebook

it is very simple

here is css

```
.social_vk, .social_fb {        
    height: 38px;
    object-fit: contain;
    cursor : pointer;
    opacity: 1;
}

.social_vk:hover, .social_fb:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

here is html

```
<div class="social">
<img src="/images/vk.svg" class="social_share social_vk" data-    type="vk" onmtouchstart="this.style.opacity = '0.8'" ontouchend ="this.style.opacity = '1'">
<img src="/images/facebook.svg" class="social_share social_fb" data-type="fb" ontouchstart="this.style.opacity = '0.8'" ontouchend="this.style.opacity = '1'">
```

So. problem is that by tapping on this button it opens modal window (facebook) and opacity of the button remains 0.8

I'm not sure but i'm stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing styles via the `styles` property can have some unintended side-effects because they are inlined. So instead just add/remove another class from it and you'll have a better time working with it.

Here is the main change:
`ontouchstart="this.classList.add('hover')" ontouchend="this.classList.remove('hover')"`.

Do note:

> [**The touchstart event will only work on devices with a touch screen.**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_touchstart.asp)

```css
.social_vk, .social_fb {        
    height: 38px;
    object-fit: contain;
    cursor : pointer;
    opacity: 1;
}

.social_vk:hover, .social_fb:hover ,
.social_vk.hover, .social_fb.hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<div class="social">
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP8z8BQDwAEhQGAhKmMIQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" class="social_share social_vk" data-type="vk" ontouchstart="this.classList.add('hover')" ontouchend ="this.classList.remove('hover')">
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNkiPlfDwADmwHcaV65UQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" class="social_share social_fb" data-type="fb" ontouchstart="this.classList.add('hover')" ontouchend="this.classList.remove('hover')">
```